# Serializing both to local and SOAP with private members c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, private-members

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I am trying to serialize some classes for dual use: 1) to save data locally in XML format and 2) to send the classes to a web service using SOAP.

There are some (private) members in the class that I want to save locally, but I do not want them over the wire.  Is there a way to do this without having 2 near copies of the same class (one with the private members, and the other without)?

Edit: The point of this post is not to determine which is the best way for me to serialize private members, but to figure out a way to serialize my data locally so I can save the ALL my class information in XML on my local box, and yet still be able to serialize a defined subset of those members so I can pass them through SOAP to a web service.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: XML Serialization never serializes private members, so the better question would be how to get private members to serialize at all.

Comment: Assume then that those members are public.
Or I can use another serialization method that will serialize private members.

Comment: @John - specifically, `XmlSerializer` doesn't. You could argue that `DataContractSerializer` can be used for (very limited) "XML Serialization", but *does* work on private members.

Comment: @Marc: picky, picky! Yes, I meant that `XmlSerializer` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) that's what WCF uses for SOAP purposes, and with the DataContract you can decorate private members as participating in serialization

Here's a good link for DataContract usage 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have read about this and this is probably what I am going to implement, however I think you missed the point of my post.  It is not to determine which is the best way for me to serialize private members, but to figure out a way to serialize my data locally so I can save the ALL my class information in XML on my local box, and yet still be able to serialize a subset of those members so I can pass them through SOAP to a web service.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you needed two representations. You might consider using the XamlSerializer (note Xaml not Xml) for your local XML generation, and then the DataContractSerializer for your subset generation.